# Error: Python module tensorflow was not found. Rstudio, Windows10 - PATH problem

Tags: r, windows, tensorflow, path

I am trying to install **TensorFlow** on my **RStudio** for **Windows10** following the official instructions found in the website https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/

and with the requisite found in the official TensorFlow webs
https://www.tensorflow.org/install?hl=en

I found this is still an unsolved problem considering that nobody could really help in the previous questions like this for example ([R, TensorFlow, Anaconda Install on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025728/r-tensorflow-anaconda-install-on-windows))

So I followed many videos on youtube and read a lot but still nothing. When I run:

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")


library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
tf_config()

Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\Simone\anaconda3\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe
 C:\Users\Simone\anaconda3\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

I tried this after tried the way suggested in the official page

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
```

but still, same thing. I think it's a PATH problem but I don't know how to solve it.
Consider that when I run:

```
py_config() #then i get this
python:         C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  9 2020, 00:29:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.4
tensorflow:     C:\Users\Simone\ANACON~2\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p

python versions found: 
 C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
 C:/Users/Simone/anaconda3/python.exe
```

**TensorFlow** seems to be installed in this **PATH**  C:\Users\Simone\ANACON~2\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.p but manually checking this **PATH** it doesn't appear. Seems like **python** is installed in one path, and **tensorflow** in another one

Any idea how I could fix the path problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT1:**
I also noticed this warning message from  `install_tensorflow()`

```
WARNING: The script tensorboard.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Simo\ANACON~2\envs\R-RETI~1\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

so that would be the problem I should solve, but don't know how

Comment: As per the warning can you try to add the mentioned path manually and try.

Comment: i tried but nothing :(

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem of intalling tensorflow in Rstudio, but I found a way to avoid it by installing tensorflow in a new anaconda environment, then activate the envirnoment inside Rstudio. It works in my computer (win 11, R4.2.1).

1. install anaconda
2. create a new tensorflow environment named tf-gpu, open **anaconda prompt** and run:

   conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu

   conda activate tf-gpu

You can check the environment in anaconda prompt by:

```
conda env list
```

3. open Rstudio and run:

   library("tensorflow")

   use_condaenv("tf-gpu", required = TRUE)

   tf$constant("Hello Tensorflow!")

Comment: THANK YOU.

Note: One already creates a conda environment named 'tf', if one follows the official instructions (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2). One can use that environment instead of creating yet another one named 'tf-gpu'. Thus, 
use_condaenv("tf", required = TRUE).